# Android - Bottom Navigation View & Navigation Bar inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview

I got a problem in my Android application, I have one Activity with multiples Fragments inside. The layout of this activity is here :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_fond_opacite"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigationAvis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.luseen.luseenbottomnavigation.BottomNavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationAvis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:bnv_active_color="@color/vraiment_pro_vert"
            app:itemBackground="@color/vraiment_pro_fond_gris"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/vraiment_pro_fond_gris"
            app:bnv_active_text_size="@dimen/bottom_navigation_text_size_active"
            app:bnv_colored_background="true"
            app:bnv_inactive_text_size="@dimen/bottom_navigation_text_size_inactive"
            app:bnv_with_text="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My problem is that the **BottomNavigationView** doesn't display on my phone with a virtual **Navigation Bar** (Huawei phone). But it perfectly works with my Samsung Galaxy S6.

I directly thought it was the virtual Navigation Bar that was hiding the BottomNavigationview so I tried to hide it with the code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html).
And it showed that I was right, but it doesn't solve my problem, because I don't want to hide the Navigation Bar and it can't be permanent.

After that, I tried to display my **BottomNavigationView** in a simple activity and it's working fine on the Huawei.

So I think it's a problem that happens inside a Fragment, maybe caused by the DrawerLayout or another thing in my code ?

If someone had already encounter this problem, please help me ! Thank you !